# Wordpress - Child theme doens't load my css on new index.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have some problems with the css style and child theme. I create a child theme starting with Twenty Twenty One theme of wordpress.

Style css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-One Child
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone/
Template: twentytwentyone
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: Twenty Twenty-One is a blank canvas for your ideas and it makes the block editor your best brush. With new block patterns, which allow you to create a beautiful layout in a matter of seconds, this theme’s soft colors and eye-catching — yet timeless — design will let your work shine. Take it for a spin! See how Twenty Twenty-One elevates your portfolio, business website, or personal blog.
Tags: one-column,accessibility-ready,custom-colors,custom-menu,custom-logo,editor-style,featured-images,footer-widgets,block-patterns,rtl-language-support,sticky-post,threaded-comments,translation-ready
Version: 1.1.1609775076
Updated: 2021-01-04 16:44:36

*/

h2{
    background-color:red;
}
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
}
```

Ok, lets start the theme and ok, i see the bg of h2 changing in red but .. if i create in my child theme directory my file index.php i dont see the style!

index.php

```
<h2>hello!</h2>
```

There is no style, no call of my stylesheet in "network" console. I dont understand! Why if i create an index.php wordpress doesn't load my style? where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably useful to look at the `index.php` or other phps supplied by the theme to see what they do.

Wordpress does allow you to write completely 'vanilla' templates, overriding all its normal headers/footers.

I suspect you need to look at the `get_header()` function, but best to start by looking at what your chosen theme does normally and build on that.